# How to count spaces for 2nd column in any file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to count the lines which do not have any words separated by spaces.

Example  in domainlist.txt:

```
Hi My name is Ritesh Mishra
my.name
my
```

There the script should should give the output: 2

I have witten below code

```
#!/bin/bash
param=" "
cat domainlist.txt | while read line
do
d=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}' `
if [[ $d == $param  ]];
then
let count++
fi
done
echo $count
```

It should count the lines which do not have any space-separated words. But its not showing any inputs.

Comment: _"its not showing any inputs."_. Do you mean outputs ?

Comment: Yes! outputs i mean

Answer (score 1):

Using awk *to count the lines which doesn't have any space separated word*:

```
$ awk 'NF==1{c++}END{print c}' file
2
```

Comment: To handle empty lines, you might want `NF < 2`

Comment: Just in case, you did command: `awk 'NF<2{c++}END{print c}' file`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like we are overcomplicating this.
Why not just grep?

```
$: cat file
Hi My name is Ritesh Mishra
my.name
my
$: grep -vc ' ' file
2
```

Comment: Accept the solution? Even if it's the easy way, simple is good, right? ;)